# Why is $\cos\theta$ used in three-dimensional geometry in place of $\tan\theta$ or $\sin\theta$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, 3d

While going through the introduction of 3D geometry, I'm finding the discussion starts with $\cos\theta$ called "direction cosines".

My query is, in 2D geometry, we find simpler and clear to understand equations of a line as $y= mx+ c$, so

1. Why all of a sudden we introduce $\cos\theta$ and also take help of a parallel vector which is not a part of the line?
2. Why do we depend on a vector introduction? Can not the equation of a line be derived using its own points?
3. Why can not it be used with $\tan\theta$ or $\sin\theta$ notations?
4. Why is it that the equation $ax+by+cz+ d=0$, which looks like the equation of a straight line, is the equation of a plane?
5. Due to all this 3D happens to be inaccessible to understand in the introduction itself. Why it becomes so complex?
6. Can 2D geometry be done using cosine or sine functions? or is $\tan\theta$ fixed for it, and $\cos\theta$ is fixed for 3D geometry?

Thanks.

Comment: In English, it’s “theta”. Also, please use MatJax to code mathematics.

Comment: This question is very vague.

Comment: @sachin: I have attempted to make your question(s) more clear. Please double-check that I have property captured your intent.

Comment: @Blue,yes its absolutely correct,thanks a lot.

Comment: I am guessing that sachin is not a native English speaker.  Nonetheless, I have upvoted the question, and wish to see it remain open.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. If you have six separate questions, ask one first and then understand the answers given there before you ask another one.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous formulations for lines in 2D and 3D. Some have direct analogies and some do not.

Here is a sampling of different ways to define a line in both 2D and 3D.

$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
\text{formulation} & \text{2D} & \text{3D}\\
\hline \text{ray from point} & \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r_{x}\\
r_{y}
\end{pmatrix}+t\,\begin{pmatrix}e_{x}\\
e_{y}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r_{x}\\
r_{y}\\
r_{z}
\end{pmatrix}+t\,\begin{pmatrix}e_{x}\\
e_{y}\\
e_{z}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{between two points} & \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=(1-t)\begin{pmatrix}a_{x}\\
a_{y}
\end{pmatrix}+t\,\begin{pmatrix}b_{x}\\
b_{y}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=(1-t)\begin{pmatrix}a_{x}\\
a_{y}\\
a_{z}
\end{pmatrix}+t\,\begin{pmatrix}b_{x}\\
b_{y}\\
b_{z}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{implicit} & e_{x}\,(y-r_{y})+e_{y}\,(r_{x}-x)=0 & \begin{pmatrix}e_{y}\,(z-r_{z})+e_{z}\,(r_{y}-y)=0\\
e_{x}\,(z-r_{z})+e_{z}\,(r_{x}-x)=0\\
e_{x}\,(y-r_{y})+e_{y}\,(r_{x}-x)=0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{Plücker} & \begin{pmatrix}m_{z}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}e_{x}\\
e_{y}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}m_{x}\\
m_{y}\\
m_{z}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}e_{x}\\
e_{y}\\
e_{z}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{equation} & a\,x+b\,y+c=0 & \dfrac{x-r_{x}}{e_{x}}=\dfrac{y-r_{y}}{e_{y}}=\dfrac{z-r_{z}}{e_{z}}=t\\
\text{slope-intercept} & y=m\,x+b & ?\\
\text{angle }\varphi\text{-offset }d & x\,\sin\varphi-y\cos\varphi=d & \text{N/A}\\
\text{projective meet} & \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}n_{y}\\
n_{x}\\
-d
\end{pmatrix}=0 & \begin{aligned}\begin{pmatrix}e_{x}\\
e_{y}\\
e_{z}
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{pmatrix}n_{x}\\
n_{y}\\
n_{z}
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}n_{x}\\
n_{y}\\
n_{z}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}m_{x}\\
m_{y}\\
m_{z}
\end{pmatrix} & =d_{1}\begin{pmatrix}n_{x}\\
n_{y}\\
n_{z}
\end{pmatrix}-d_{2}\begin{pmatrix}n_{x}\\
n_{y}\\
n_{z}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{array}$$

In the above list ($x$,$y$ ..) denotes a point on the line, ($r_x$,$r_y$..) denotes a known point, ($e_x$,$e_y$ ..) denotes line direction vector, ($n_x$,$n_y$ ..) denotes perpendicular direction, $t$ is either a free parameter or a constant,  ($a$,$b$,$c$) are equation coefficients, $\varphi$ is the direction angle from horizontal of a 2D line and $d$ the offset of the line from the origin. Oh ,and ($m_x$,$m_y$ ..) are parameters that describe the *moment* of the line about the origin. And ($a_x$,$a_y$..) ($b_x$,$b_y$..) are the coordinates of two points.

---

I am not sure where you see a $\cos \varphi$ to define a line, but my guess is that you saw that in the context of the dot product $\cdot$

$$ \| a \cdot b \| = \| a \| \| b \| \cos \varphi $$

This particular identity isn't of much use for defining lines. The question needs more details to be answered fully.

Comment: Just a minor note: *intersept* in slope-intersept should be spelled as *intercept* as in slope-intercept.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris - thank you. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I count six questions there.  Taking #4, the reason $ax + by + cz = d$ is a plane is because we are in three dimensions. Each linear equation is a constraint, and reduces the dimension of the space by one.  So when you are in two dimensions, one equation reduces it to a line.  When you are in three dimensions, one equation reduces it to a plane.  In higher dimensions one linear equation restricts to an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, and is called a "hyperplane".

If you start with the equation of a line in two dimensions, say $y = 2x + 3$, if you move to three dimensions and write the same equation, that equation has no restriction on z.  So if you take the line in the x-y plane in 3D and move it directly up and down to different values of z, you will get a plane parallel to the z axis.  Tilted planes require the more general $ax + by + cz = d$.

Comment: are u meaning the 2d equation of a line is fixed and when it comes to 3d it rotates keeping the slope with x axis the same,so it gives rise to many straight lines making eventually a plane,i.e the locus of the line with same slope with x axis becomes a plane,thanks.

Comment: Edited to add example.